# Debug Java Code called via JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a piece of code where I am creating a Java VM via JNI and then invoking a method on a java .class file.

How do i debug the java code via an IDE say eclipse or Netbeans.
My c++ project is setup in visual studio and the java project is setup using eclipse.
Till now I was using logs to debug the java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use remote debugging see http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-debug-remote-java-applicat

Comment: Does this mean that at JNI layer, where I am calling CreateJVM I need to pass the "-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=<portno>,server=y" as a option to the VM?

Comment: yes, that's correct. However, In the java control panel, in the java tab, you can set properties there, altho i don't know that settings you put there will be picked up by jvm's loaded thru jni. You might try that first. I don't know never tried it. But what you say will work.

Comment: Tried it the following set of options work -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y,suspend=n