# Debugging Java code by attach to process in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on an application created using vb6, C++ and Java. I need to debug Java code of application. I am trying to debug it using remote debugging of eclipse but I am getting this error - "Could not find or load main class".

Any method by which I can debug such Java code.

Comment: `debug it using remote debugging of eclipse` Is the application running on a server? Is the debug mode enabled for the server?

Comment: I am running this application locally. The application has vb6 exe as UI. It uses other Java and C++ files to perform operations. So, I can debug the C++ code by attach to process from Visual Studio. But I dont know how to do that using eclipse. I am new to Java development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able debug the Java code of my application. I passed the remote debugging argument in the vb6 code during Java initialization (JVM creation). This setting helped me to debug Java code in eclipse IDE. I found the details from this post-

[Debug Java Code called via JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864865/debug-java-code-called-via-jnitauk)

You can get detail information from here -
http://newapputil.blogspot.in/2013/10/debug-java-and-jni-c-code.html